# Was ist „gut” in „gut Ding will Weile haben”?

Tags: phrase

In

> gut Ding will Weile haben

ahne ich, dass das Adjektiv *gut* ausgeschrieben *gutes* hieße. Wie soll ich das *gut* interpretieren? Ist das Dialekt, altes Deutsch, eine Abkürzung der Art *ich hab 'ne Frage*?

Comment: Ich hätte vermutet, eine nicht mehr gebräuchliche Flexionsmorphologie, aber anscheinend ist das Pattern doch noch produktiv: https://www.ds.uzh.ch/_files/uploads/studarb/24.pdf

Comment: A bit of context for those of us who aren't familiar, this seems to be a proverb similar in meaning to "Haste makes waste". *Eile mit Weile* is closer in meaning to the English, so maybe "Quality takes time", but that sounds like an advertising slogan.

Comment: @phipsgabler: Das sieht aus, als könnte man es in eine gute Antwort verwandeln.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Das ist altes Deutsch und steht so bei Goethe, in [Wilhelm Meisters Wanderjahre](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilhelm_Meisters_Wanderjahre#Zitate). Es bedeutet "Ein gutes Ding will Weile haben", heute würde man wohl sagen "braucht Geduld" oder "muss reifen".
Stehende Redewendungen, Literaturzitate und auch Textstellen aus Liedern widerstehen oft einem geänderten Sprachgebrauch.
[Hier](https://www.aphorismen.de/zitat/159316) wird das Zitat Ovid zugeschrieben, der jedoch nicht auf Deutsch veröffentlicht hat. Wann der Satzt exakt so übersetzt wurde ist dem Link so wenig entnehmbar, wie die genauere Kennzeichnung des Textes, also Titel, Verlag, Jahr, Seitenzahl.
1821 erschienen das Goethesche Werk, [Google NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gut%20Ding%20will%20Weile%20haben&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgut%20Ding%20will%20Weile%20haben%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cgut%20Ding%20will%20Weile%20haben%3B%2Cc1) verzeichnet einen Peak für den Ausdruck jedoch 5-10 Jahre früher.

So ist also denkbar, dass sich Goethe in einem Wörterbuch bedient hat, die Redewendung dadurch populär wurde, und Ovid erst daraufhin so übersetzt wurde. Ebenso kann aber die Ovidübersetzung für das Redensartenverzeichnis Pate gestanden haben oder letzeres für beide, Goethe und die Ovidübersetzung. Oder die Redensart mag auch ohne schriftliche Fixierung populär gewesen sein.

Answer (score 2):

Mit dem Alter hat das wenig zu tun, es handelt sich um eine Aussparung aus Stilgründen. Die Redensart gewinnt dadurch an Prägnanz und klanglicher Harmonie.

Anderes Beispiel für die Wirkung von Aussparungen:

> Wo kein Kläger, da kein Richter *statt* Wo kein Kläger ist, da ist auch kein Richter

Wer einen Spruch in Umlauf bringen will, tut gut daran, ihn in eine ansprechende Form zu bringen, das fördert die Verbreitung.

Answer (score 1):

[Diese Webseite](https://www.heinrich-tischner.de/22-sp/9sp-ecke/fragen/200/2008/gut-ding.htm) erklärt die Herkunft des Ausdrucks wie folgt:

> Das ist der Sprache nach aus der Zeit um 1500, da schrieb man tatsächlich "gut Ding" und nicht "gutes Ding".

Leider wird dort aber auch keine Quelle, bzw. genauere Erläuterung angegeben.

Das Zitat lässt sich allerdings wahrscheinlich auf Martin Luther (1483-1546) zurückführen. Schaut man im DWB nach, findet man unter dem [Eintrag "GUT (4)"](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GG32499#XGG32499)

> gut ding wil weil haben - Luthers

Eine Zuschreibung, die man auch an [anderen](https://www.sachsen-lese.de/index.php?article_id=640) [Stellen](https://heinrich-tischner.de/22-sp////4stil/sprw/xyz/zeit.htm) findet.

Für die Behauptung auf der Webseite, dass man damals "tatsächlich so schrieb" kann man auch im [DWB unter "Ding"](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GD02497#XGD02497) nachschauen, um zumindest Hinweise zu finden, die das untermauern.

Auch dort finden sich Textpassagen wie:

> ja, das war schon ein ander ding
>
> (die Preuszen) haben kein münz, bawen schlecht ding, von leimen und stroh ein hütlin
>
> har das ist ein klein ding
>
> zorn ist ein wütig ding
>
> etc.

aber auch [Sachen wie](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GG32499#XGG32499)

> ein gut wort findet eine gute statt

welches sich [gewandelt hat](https://www.sprichwoerter.net/deutsche-sprichwoerter-und-redewendungen/g/gutes-wort-findet-gute-statt.html) in

> Gutes Wort findet gute Statt.

so dass man wirklich davon ausgehen kann, dass "Gut Ding will Weile haben" ein alter Ausdruck ist, der sich durch die Zeit gerettet hat.

EDIT:

Schaut man in "Proverbiorvm Copia, Etlich viel Hundert, Lateinischer vnd Teutscher schöner vnd lieblicher Sprichwörter - Eyering, Eucharius" von 1601 findet man "[viel weiter Ding](https://reader.digitale-sammlungen.de/de/fs1/object/context/bsb10576112_00001.html?contextSort=score%2Cdescending&contextType=scan&context=gut%20ding&contextStart=10&contextRows=10)"

> [All Ding zu rechter Zeit ausrichten](https://reader.digitale-sammlungen.de/de/fs1/object/display/bsb10576112_00037.html?contextSort=score%2Cdescending&contextType=scan&contextRows=10&contextStart=10&context=gut%20ding)
>
> [Desgleichen gut Ding will Weile han](https://reader.digitale-sammlungen.de/de/fs1/object/display/bsb10576112_00182.html?contextSort=score%2Cdescending&contextType=scan&contextRows=10&context=gut%20ding)
>
> [Iß und trink gern gut Ding und Wein](https://reader.digitale-sammlungen.de/de/fs1/object/display/bsb10576112_00216.html?contextSort=score%2Cdescending&contextType=scan&contextRows=10&context=gut%20ding)